# Change Color of just one instantiated object in Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

In my game I instantiated many objects from a prefab, then after a few seconds, I select one object as a target so I want to change the color of just that one object in Unity.

I tried diferents options of previous questions

```
gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = mycolor;
```

and also

```
 Renderer victimRender = target.GetComponent<Renderer>();
 victimRender.material.color = Color.black;
```

But I get the following error

```
Not allowed to access Renderer.material on prefab object. Use Renderer.sharedMaterial instead
```

And if I use sharedMaterial insteat of material, it changes the prefab material so all objects change their color.

It's possible to change the color of just one instantied object?

UPDATE

I instantiate the game objects in other script and store them in an array
in the current script I want to access one random position of the array and get one gameObject

```
 
        victimMaterial = Resources.Load<Material>("VictimMaterial");       
        target = SpawnerController.sharedInstance.citizens[victim];
        MeshRenderer victimRenderer = target.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();          
        victimRender.material = victimMaterial;
```

Instead of getting the cloned object, it's getting the prefab so I cannot change the color of adding other material to it's Mesh Render

If only I could reference the cloned object instead it's prefab I could easily change the color.

Also in game mode I can drag the material to it's mesh render and it change the color of that particular object, so I'm sure it must be a way to achieve it

Comment: Apparently you are trying to change the color of a **prefab asset**, not the actually instantiated object in your scene .... I think it would help to see your full code and how and where it is called exactly

Comment: If citizens is an array of prefabs then you are acting in it and that'd be the problem. After the second line where u get the target use var obj = Instantiate(target); to see if that does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are refencing the instantiated Object instead of the prefab.

This should work for you:

```
GameObject instance = Instantiate(prefab);

instance.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color =
                new Color(Random.Range(0f, 1f), Random.Range(0f, 1f), Random.Range(0f, 1f),1f);
```

Comment: Thanks to all for answering, The solution was adding the instance object to the array, doing so, I can modify freerly it's cloned objects instead the prefab.